# UIBezierPath & CAShapeLayer initial animation jump

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I built this for my company: https://github.com/busycm/BZYStrokeTimer and during the course of building, I noticed an interesting "bug" that I can't seem to mitigate when using `UIBezierPath`. Right when the animation starts, the path jumps a certain number of pixels forward (or backwards depending if it's counterclockwise) instead of starting up with a smooth, incremental animation. And what I found that's really interesting is how much the path jumps forward is actually the value of the line width for the `CAShaperLayer`.

So for example, if my bezier path starts off at `CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds)` and the line with is 35, the animation actually starts from `CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds)+35` and the larger the line width, the more noticeable the jump is. Is there any way to get rid of that so that path will smoothly animate out from the start point?

Here's a picture of the first frame. This is what it looks like immediately after the animation starts. [image]

Then when I resume the animation and pause again, the distance moved is about 1/100th of the distance you see in the picture.

Here's my bezier path code:

```
- (UIBezierPath *)generatePathWithXInset:(CGFloat)dx withYInset:(CGFloat)dy clockWise:(BOOL)clockwise{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds)+dx/2, dy/2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds)-dx/2, dy/2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds)-dx/2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.bounds)-dy/2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(dx/2, CGRectGetMaxY(self.bounds)-dy/2)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(dx/2, dy/2)];
    [path closePath];
    return clockwise ? path : [path bezierPathByReversingPath];
}
```

Here's the animation code:

```
CABasicAnimation *wind = [self generateAnimationWithDuration:self.duration == 0 ? kDefaultDuration : self.duration fromValue:@(self.shapeLayer.strokeStart) toValue:@(self.shapeLayer.strokeEnd) withKeypath:keypath withFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
wind.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:self.timingFunction];
wind.removedOnCompletion = NO;
self.shapeLayer.path = [self generatePathWithXInset:self.lineWidth withYInset:self.lineWidth clockWise:self.clockwise].CGPath;
[self.shapeLayer addAnimation:wind forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
```

And here's how I construct the `CAShapeLayer`.

```
- (CAShapeLayer *)shapeLayer {
    return !_shapeLayer ? _shapeLayer = ({
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        layer.lineWidth = kDefaultLineWidth;
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;
        layer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        layer.lineCap = kCALineCapSquare;
        layer.frame = self.bounds;
        layer.strokeStart = 0;
        layer.strokeEnd = 1;
        layer;
    }) : _shapeLayer;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a video of what this looks like, or at least the first frame of the animation? I'm having trouble visualizing exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah I did. It's not a problem so much as I can't figure out how to either get rid of it or if this is the default behavior of `CAShapeLayer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what's happening here is that, in this frame of the animation, you are drawing a line that consists of a single point. Since the line has a thickness associated with it, and the line cap type is `kCALineCapSquare`, that'll get rendered as a square with height and width equal to the line width.

You can think of it as if you are drawing a line with a square marker, and you are going to drag the midpoint of the marker so that it goes through every point in the curve you specified. For the first point in the line, it's as if the marker touches down at that point, leaving a square behind.

[Here's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Art/linecaps_objectivec.gif) a visual representation the different line cap types that will hopefully make it more intuitive. You should probably change the line cap style to `kCALineCapButt`.

**Sidenote:** 
After you make that change, in this line of code

`[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds)+dx/2, dy/2)];`

you probably don't have to offset the `x` coordinate by `dx/2` anymore.

Comment: I changed the line cap to `kCALineCapButt` and it works exactly as I would expect it to. Thanks, never would have caught that